# how to use if else conditions in scss

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have following variables defined in scss

```
:root {
  --color-in: none;
  --color-out: none;
}
```

I am setting their values from javascript.

How can i write if else conditions on these like if they are not undefined then do this else do that. I tried following code but its not working.

```
@if var(--color-in) && var(--color-out) {
  background:
  linear-gradient(to left, transparent, rgba(255,255,255,.5)),
  linear-gradient(to left, var(--color-in), var(--color-out));
} @else {
  background-color: currentColor;
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this is what you want, but if you use "normal" variables, you can use `@if variable-exists(...)`.

A short example:

```
$color_in: #ff0000;
[...]
@if variable-exists($color_in)
    /* do stuff */
@else
    /* do other stuff */
```

This will only work for Sass > 3.2.x, for earlier versions, you'd need to use a trick using a mixin which set's the stuff with a `!default` flag.

More on @if and such stuff: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

---

**Edit:**
I just realized, this probably isn't at all what you wanted. IMO what you want isn't possible. Sass gets compiled to CSS, at compile time, there will be one state. When that state is changed by Javascript, you would have to recompile your Sass code to CSS again in the browser (which is theoretically possible). To understand the difference of CSS Variables and Sass/SCSS Variables take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/difference-between-types-of-css-variables/

What I'd recommend you, is to set CSS classes on your body element by Javascript, and have one class per color. You can define an array of colors and their names in Sass and loop over it, to generate all needed classes!

Another thing to take into account: Internet Explorer doesn't support CSS Variables (https://www.caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables). Depending on what statistics you look at, IE still has a market share of 2%-14%. Take a look at your own user statistics to determine if IE support is crucial for you.